# Preg_match PHP to java translation

Tags: java, php, preg-match

I am having some trouble converting a php pregmatch to java.  I thought I had it all correct but it doesn't seem to be working. Here is the code:

Original PHP:

```
/* Pattern for 44 Character UUID */
$pattern = "([0-9A-F\-]{44})";
if (preg_match($pattern,$content)){
                /*DO ACTION*/
            }
```

My Java code:

```
final String pattern = "([0-9A-F\\-]{44})";
    public static boolean pregMatch(String pattern, String content) {
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
            Matcher m = p.matcher(content);
            boolean b = m.matches();
            return b;
        }
if (pregMatch(pattern, line)) {
                        //DO ACTION
                    }
```

So my test input is:
DBA40365-7346-4DB4-A2CF-52ECA8C64091-0

Using a series of System.outs I get that b = false.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To implement a function as you did in your code:

```
final String pattern = "[0-9A-F\\-]{44}";
public static boolean pregMatch(String pattern, String content) {
    return content.matches(pattern);
}
```

And then you can call it as:

```
if (pregMatch(pattern, line)) {
    //DO ACTION
}
```

You don't need the parenthesis in your `pattern` because that just creates a match group, which you are not using. If you need access to back references, you would need the parenthesis an a more advanced regex code using `Pattern` and `Matcher` classes.

Comment: I can't tell if the lines I'm trying to match is the issue or not.  Some examples are: B3AF08DE-7F02-450B-A316-94AB10603956-0      ||| 83202015-E001-422C-9792-1D298893A289-0            |||     DBA40365-7346-4DB4-A2CF-52ECA8C64091-0   Is there something wrong with these lines that they fail or perhaps something else wrong in my code?

Comment: Those strings are 38 characters long, and your regex is trying to match 44 characters with `{44}`. Use the regex pattner `[0-9A-F\\-]{38}` and it will match each one of those values. If you want to match strings 38 to 44 characters long, use `[0-9A-F\\-]{38,44}`

Answer (score 6):

You could just use `String.matches()`

```
if (line.matches("[0-9A-F-]{44}")) {
  // do action
}
```