# Incompatibility when porting PHP preg_match logic to Java using String.matches

Tags: java, php, regex

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13013695/preg-match-php-to-java-translation) on how to port PHP's `preg_match` to Java (it recommends using `String.matches()`. However, I still have trouble with the following situation:

**PHP**:

`preg_match('/<(h1|h2|h3|h4|ul|td|div|table)/i', '<h1>')` => returns `1`

**Java**:

`"<h1>".matches("/<(h1|h2|h3|h4|ul|td|div|table)/i")` => return `false`

Why would that be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, `matches()` requires a  full string match. And you do not need regex delimiters.

```
"<h1>".matches("(?i)<(h1|h2|h3|h4|ul|td|div|table)>")
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/pX4Z00)

If you plan to use the same regex in Java, use `Matcher` with `find()` (`find` will match anywhere in the input string and `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE` will act as `i` option in PHP):

```
String str = "<h1>";
String rx = "<(h1|h2|h3|h4|ul|td|div|table)";
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile(rx, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher m = ptrn.matcher(str);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(0));
}
```

See [another demo](http://ideone.com/xBqnLi)

Comment: Is there a less horrible API than `Patter.compile` thing?

Comment: If you ask me for a substitution, I do not know any. I just provided this to show how you can use the same regex in Java and PHP *without editing the regex itself*. You can actually write a separate wrapper method to simplify invoking the replacement, but you will still have to add the `import java.util.regex.*;` import.

Answer (score 1):

- You need to remove the regex delimiters.
- And also you need to add `(?i)` modifier for doing case-insensitive match.
- Finally you have tyo add `>` at the last since `matches` method tries to match the whole string.

  ```
  "<h1>".matches("(?i)<(h1|h2|h3|h4|ul|td|div|table)>");
  ```

Comment: Sorry I realised that this is not a correct answer. While php version would match `<h1>hello</h1>`, java version wouldn't

Comment: then you need to use `Pattern and Matcher classes.`

Answer (score 0):

In Java it should be:

```
"<h1>".matches("(?i)<(h[1234]|ul|td|div|table)>");
```

i.e. no regex delimiter and `(?i)` for ignore-case comparison.